# Titlebar Changing on opening MacBook Air M1 terminal

Tags: terminal, python, apple-silicon

On opening the terminal on my MacBook Air M1, the following happens.[See link](https://youtu.be/EKQBZE7psLc)

The terminal titlebar changes from login to python to zsh. i dont understand how python is getting echoed.

zprofile

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql-8.0.31-macos12-arm64/bin
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)

# Setting PATH for Python 3.10
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

zshrc

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/kartikeydoshi/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/kartikeydoshi/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/kartikeydoshi/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
```

how do i stop python from appearing when i open the terminal? The terminal should open directly without having a python change in the terminal.

Comment: Well, if you have Terminal set to show the running command in the title *and* your zsh startup scripts call `python`, then you *will* briefly see python in the title. Not sure what exactly you worry about here.

Comment: Code is a little bit different from the code in the official installation instructions of `pyenv` for `zsh`, but might not be relevant: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#set-up-your-shell-environment-for-pyenv Title bar changing, doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: Title bar changing is normal, I also see the title bar change in my Terminal for some split microseconds when I open it up, though not for Python. However, if you're looking for peace of mind, you can easily disable showing the active process in the title bar by going to: Terminal --> Settings... --> Profiles --> Window --> unchecking Active process name.

Comment: `pyenv` is a shell script, so it's probably your `conda` initialization that is calling `python`.